# Developing call/vocie recording app (iphone)?

Tags: iphone

I want to make an iphone application to record the incoming and outgoing calls. If I can't develop such app , What are the technology and hardware hindrance in doing so ? BTW i was thinking to run my app in background while call, Hence recording the input and output voice through my app .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iPhone application doesn't have access to the voice channel in an iPhone in any circumstances. Which is a good thing, as having a background application recording voice could have very bad side effects.

Comment: The techological hinderance is that the user level iPhone software has no access. Technically there isn't that much of a hardware hinderance

Comment: I was thinking to make a voice recorder and run it on call . e.g When someone presses the call button my app/service will run in background or somewhere on foreground. Is this thing possible?

Comment: No. You can record from the microphone, or audio input, and you can play from the speaker, but you can't record or play into the phone signal, if that is what you are asking

Answer (score -1):

Apple has a lot of awesome tutorial code.
below url is speakHere that Apple recording sample code.
this code maybe some would be help to you. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: That doesn't record incoming phone calls, it records sound from the audio input while the phone is not in a call. In a call it will be suspended for the duration of the call and then start again when the call is terminated.